# how to run java selnium junit Tests using groovy

Tags: java, selenium, groovy, junit4

I am using ReadyAPI which use Groovy as Scripting language.

But, I built a Selenium 4 framework which Tests some IHMs in my work using java8 and Junit4, and it works very fine.

Please, can you help me on how to run my Java Juint Tests using Groovy Script.

`
package com.cegedim.framework.scenarios;

```
 import com.cegedim.framework.functional.Transverse;
 import com.cegedim.framework.functional.modules.LoginModule;
 import com.cegedim.framework.functional.webpages.url.URLS;
 import com.cegedim.framework.reporting.Reporter;
 import com.cegedim.framework.utils.TestBase;
 import org.junit.Test;

 public class TestLogin extends TestBase {
     @Test
     public void main() {
    Reporter.getInstance().logInfo("Start Login Test Case.");
    Transverse.get(URLS.TPG_URL);
    LoginModule.login("rootfab", "profils", "EXPLOIT");
    Reporter.getInstance().logInfo("Finish Login Test Case.");
}
```

}`
Error[image: Error] In readyAPIwhich uses Groovy as Scripting language in the image.

Thank you.

Comment: Groovy based on java. So, in general you could continue writing java. If you have particular error then show your code and error message.

Comment: Please edit your question and put updates there.

Comment: Are you running this code in ReadyAPI as Groovy script step ? If so, look at the Groovy version in ReadyAPI, look at your required jars for your code and match compatability with the jars in ReadyAPI. Did you add the jars in the correct location for ReadyAPI to load ? Please add your comments to your original question and delete the comments.

Comment: I edited the question and put the sample code used.
For the jars i used the maven command
`mvn clean compile assembly:single` to generate a jar with my classes and all dependencies

Comment: No one to Help? :'(